# Ansible vars inventory

Tags: server, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm learning Ansible. And I was following the official docs:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/intro_inventory.html

But I have a little question. How use the vars in the inventories?

I have try to use some of the default parameters like *self_destruct_countdown*.

```
[pruebascomandos]
MY-SERVER-IP self_destruct_countdown=60
OTHER-MY-SERVER-IP
```

And using the apply variables to all group. With a own var.

```
[pruebascomandos:vars]
example=true
```

But my problem is that in both cases I try to check the var with:

`$ ansible pruebascomandos -m shell -a "echo $self_destruct_countdown"`

`$ ansible pruebascomandos -m shell -a "echo $example"`

And in both cases I get a blank response. I don't sure why.

If someone can explain why or tell me where to read it it would be great. Thank to everyone!

Comment: Version 2.3 is not supported anymore. Upgrade to [latest](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Double braces](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-with-jinja2) *`{{ }}`* are needed to evaluate the variable. Try this

```yaml
shell> ansible pruebascomandos -i hosts -m shell -a "echo {{ example }}"
test_01 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
true
test_02 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
true

shell> ansible pruebascomandos -i hosts -m shell -a "echo {{ self_destruct_countdown }}"
test_02 | FAILED | rc=-1 >>
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: self_destruct_countdown is undefined
test_01 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
60
```

The host *`test_02`* failed because the variable *`self_destruct_countdown`* had been defined for *`test_01`* only.

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[pruebascomandos]
test_01 self_destruct_countdown=60
test_02

[pruebascomandos:vars]
example=true
```

Comment: Thanks! Now works. I understand that variable only exist when the command AD-HOC is executed. To be used in the system need to be exported or use a playbook (its my next lesson playbooks)